# Using Scrapy/Selenium to fill fields and search on LinkedIn advanced search page

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scrapy, linkedin-api

url for LinkedIn advanced search: https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?adv=true&trk=advsrch

I am trying to fill fields and hit the submit button on the LinkedIn advanced search page using Selenium (Python).

However, when I try to send keys to the fields that I would like to fill (ex. First Name), I get this error: ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with. I'm guessing this has to do with the toggle show/hide of the advanced search frame. I had thought the advanced search frame was by default visible, but it seems the Selenium Driver does not recognize this.

How would I make these "invisble" field and submit button elements visible?

I have tried:

- using the Wait function to put a delay on the page.
- running a script to make the div element holding the advanced search page

  self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('advs').style.display='block'")
- "clicking" on the toggle show/hide button for advanced search although I am not sure I did it correctly

  self.driver.find_element_by_id("advs-link").click()

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the submit button you can see that it is a `GET` request. So you could alternatively assemble from the input fields and values you want to fill in a URL with the parameters. The only tricky value would be the `rsid` but it can be found as `"searchId"` in the site.

Then when the URL for the `GET` request is there you can use Scrapy to call that URL as a `Request` and scrape the contents.

Comment: I tried what you specified up above, but I am now encountering a problem in that elements that I am trying to select using their xpath do not exist according to scrapy response. However, the when I inspect the same page on Google Chrome, the element DOES exist. 

For example: On the results page for a search on "John," there should be a div element with id="results-container". When I use scrapy response.xpath('//div[@id="results-container]'), there are no selectors returned.